# How do I set a macro to launch every time an email arrives in a certain subfolder in outlook 2007?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a macro to export relevant field of emails in a subfolder but I need it to automatically run every time I receive a new email. In fact I only want the subject line exported, is there a script which will trigger that macro ('ExportMessagesToExcel') when an email lands in 'M_M_Asia'?

I'm in Outlook 2007.

I'll be forever grateful if anyone can help. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to use the `Application_NewMail` (or `NewMailEx`) event in `ThisOutlookSession` module to call your own macro.
2. Another way is to create a rule that runs a VBA-script, but then you VBA sub needs to handle a MailItem parameter:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub MyVBARule(poMail As MailItem)

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could add 'ItemAdd' event handler, example here:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ASIA_FOLDER_NAME As String = "M_M_Asia"
Private WithEvents m_outlookFolderItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_Handler
End Sub

Private Sub m_outlookFolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' You have new mail in folder ASIA_FOLDER_NAME
    RunExcelMacro
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize_Handler()
    Dim outlookFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim defaultInboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim outlookNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set outlookNameSpace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set defaultInboxFolder = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set outlookFolder = defaultInboxFolder.Folders(ASIA_FOLDER_NAME)
    Set m_outlookFolderItems = outlookFolder.Items
End Sub

Public Sub RunExcelMacro()
    On Error GoTo RunExcelMacro_Err

    Const path As String = "C:\temp\Excel_VBA\"
    Const fileName As String = "CallMeFromOutloouk.xlsm"
    Const macroName As String = "CallMeFromOutlook"

    Dim excelObject As Object
    Dim workbookObject As Object

    Set excelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set workbookObject = excelObject.Workbooks(fileName)
    On Error GoTo RunExcelMacro_Err

    If workbookObject Is Nothing Then
        Set workbookObject = excelObject.Workbooks.Open(path & fileName)
    End If

    excelObject.Run fileName & "!" & macroName

    Exit Sub

RunExcelMacro_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```